# VirtualBox alt+tab no longer working after upgrade to 5.1.18 for some guests but not others

Tags: virtualbox

My standard workflow for a couple years now has involved using a Debian 8 64-bit VM with Guest Additions on my Windows 8.1 64-bit host and essentially treating it as a terminal emulator, then using my host machine for everything else. I typically have the VM fullscreened and use alt+tab extensively for switching between it and my host.

After I upgraded VirtualBox on Friday to 5.1.18, I am no longer able to alt+tab away from my VM, whether in fullscreened, windowed, or in seamless mode. I can confirm that the host key is working fine and that the problem is not that the keyboard is being unexpectedly captured. Even more bizarre, I also encounter the problem on my 32-bit Debian VM and my Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit VM, but not on my Windows 7 (32-bit) or 10 (64-bit) VMs.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you downgrade to the version you were using does the functionality return?

Comment: I haven't attempted that yet; I was hoping it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It might not be required but it's the only way to confirm the problem is with the hypervisor software and not the VM itself

Comment: Given that the change happened immediately after upgrading VirtualBox and after no changes had been made to the VM, and that the problem manifested on multiple different virtual machines simultaneously, blaming the hypervisor software seems like a pretty reasonable assumption. That being said, I can attempt to downgrade later today just to be 100% certain

Comment: @Ramhound downgrading to 5.0.36 appears to have fixed my issue. That being said, I'd still like to figure out what was going wrong so I don't have to remain on this version of VB indefinitely

Comment: Have you reported the bug that you have discovered in new version of the (Linux) Vbox Additions that comes with the newer version of Vbox?

Comment: I did _not_ downgrade the installed guest additions, just the VBox software installed on my host

Comment: Have you reported the bug to the VBox community though?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Update: downgrading to 5.0.36 _appeared_ to have fixed my issue, but it just returned

Comment: did you press host key for releasing the keyboard from the VM before pressing alt+tab?

Comment: as I said in the OP, "I can confirm that the host key is working fine and that the problem is not that the keyboard is being unexpectedly captured"

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to 4.3.40 seems to have resolved the error, but still does not explain its nature.